# 2 instead of 1 output nodes in neuralnet

Tags: r, neural-network

I am using R neuralnet to do binary classification.

It worked as expected with simulated data - the neural network had 1 output node that gave the probability of the output = 1.

When I ran ionosphere dataset from UCI repository, it gives me 2 output nodes, one for FALSE and one for TRUE.

I want just one output node and struggle to understand why I'm getting 2 in the second case.

I tried to change my output labels to 0/1 instead of using TRUE/FALSE (didn't think it'd make a difference and it didn't).

```
library("neuralnet")
ion = read.delim("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ionosphere/ionosphere.data", 
                 header = FALSE, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
ion$V35[ion$V35=="g"]=TRUE # good as TRUE
ion$V35[ion$V35=="b"]=FALSE

ni = neuralnet(V35 ~ V4,
                 data = ion,
                 hidden = 1, 
                 threshold = 0.1/5,
                 stepmax = 1e+06,
                 linear.output = FALSE, 
                 act.fct = "logistic",
                 err.fct = "ce",
                 likelihood = TRUE) 
plot(ni)
```

I want something like this:
[image: one node]
<sub>(source: [ift.tt](http://ift.tt/1LHDrI0))</sub>

I get something like this:
[image: two nodes]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tW-78Igxkk0/VXApvYWlAHI/AAAAAAAAAtE/Z9XiSqR_zzg/s640/NN.PNG))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are assigning TRUE to part of the V35 variable vector, the remainder is still a character vector, so it is being coerced to the string "TRUE". Then the same thing is happening when you assign FALSE to part of the vector in the following line.

Instead, try

```
ion$V35 = (ion$V35=="g")
```

and you'll get a logical vector, and as a result a neural network output layer of one node rather than two.